# How to index and use SHA1 value as PK in oracle?

Tags: oracle, indexing, database-design, data-modeling

I am using an oracle 11g standard edition :
In order to identify some article items in my table ART_ARTICLE : I am computing a hash (sha1) based on the content of an article item and store this hash in a ART_ID column.
 I need to track change of the content of those article item : so the sha1 make a perfect solution for me.
 The fact is that all values are not sequential and I have a big clustering factor and when I have to query my table I need  most of the time a series of articles that were imported at the same time (so there were inserted one after the other in different leaf of my index)...
 This cause me some performance issue (long query when I am trying to export a previous list of articles imported for example).
 I store all version of data imported and have a revision system (a version table help me to store each import in a version. An import in a version could overload a previous import version...)

My model is as follow :

```
----------------------
TABLE : ART_ARTICLE
--------------------
ART_ID NUMBER(15) PK => computed as SHA1 from others properties (name,short_name..)
NAME
SHORT_NAME
ORIGIN
COLOR 

----------------------
TABLE : ART_ARTICLE_VERSION
--------------------
ART_VERSION PK(1)
ART_ID      PK(2) => PK composed by those 2 first fields
ART_EDIT_TYPE   (Enum in order to know if ART_ID was added/updated/remove from version ART_VERSION
```

The question I have : 
   As more I am importing new versions and list of articles, as more I have performance issues when querying all article items of a versions. 
  When I reorder the content of ART_ARTICLE by order of appearance in ART_ARTICLE_VERSION and rebuild my index on ART_ID my query is fast again.
  If I only rebuild my index after some import, I have no real gain... So I think that the fact that I have an hash as PK have an effect on the index usage.

Is there any recommandation on the way I have to create an index on my ART_ID column ?
 Does I have to recreate my table after each import and insert my ART_ID in the right order ?

Comment: Is ART_ID defined as the primary key for the table in the table create script? Can you supple the table definition, a sample query, an example explain plan showing the issue?

Comment: I have answered to APC (see below) and give more context to my question. I will also update my question in order to add detail. But effectively ART_ID is defined as a primary key on the table ART_ARTICLE

Comment: How are you generating SHA-1 values? SHA1 hashes are RAW not NUMBER.

Comment: yes you are right. I have posted my last definition where I was trying to solve the distribution of the hash by using a surrogate number(sequence) in order to have a sequential state_id. I am computing the sha-a outside of oracle in my application (c# : new SHA1Managed().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(compoundProperties) )

Answer (score 0):

> I need to track change of the content of those article item : so the sha1 make a perfect solution for me.

Not as a primary key it doesn't. Each **version** of an article will have a different primary key, so it will be impossible to track changes to the content of any given article.

In seems more likely that what you want is a compound key of `(art_id, version_no)` to store the content changes, with perhaps a parent table `article` with a primary key of just `art_id` to store the immutable attributes relating to the article (whatever they may be).

Comment: Yes you are right this is exactly what I am doing. I have a ART_ARTICLE_VERSION table (with a compound key on art_id, version_no) and my immutable table ART_ARTICLE (with a primary key on art_id)  where I store immutable state of an article in others columns (name, short_name, origin, color)

Comment: Ok, I have added more details in my initial question.